# accessing base class public member from derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance

Is it possible to access base class public member from instance of derived class in some other locations in the program.

```
class base {
public:
    int x;

    base(int xx){
    x = xx;
    }
};

class derived : base {
public:
    derived(int xx) : base(xx){
    }
};

class main {
public:
    derived * myDerived;      

    void m1(){
        myDerived = new derived(5);
        m2(myDerived);  
    }

    void m2(derived * myDerived){
        printf("%i", myDerived->x);
    }    
};
```

After above code, I got following error.

```
`error: 'int base::x' is inaccessible`
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You inherit privately from the base class. What you typically need is public inheritance:

```
class derived : public base
```

Here is the [FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/private-inheritance.html) on private inheritance.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that you accidentally use private inheritance here

```
class derived : base {
```

This makes all base class members private in the derived class.

Change this to

```
class derived : public base {
```

and it will work as expected.

Answer (score 3):

You should inherit from `base` publicly, then.

```
class derived : public base {
public:
    derived(int xx) : base(xx){
    }
};
```

Private inheritance is used in very specific circumstances, such as when you have a `has-a` relationship between two classes, but you also need to override a member of the base class.

Answer (score 1):

From outside the class, you can only access public members of public base classes; and inheritance is private by default when you define a class using the `class` keyword.

To make it accessible, you need public inheritance:

```
class derived : public base
                ^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
class derived : public base {
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use public inheritance:

```
class derived : public base {
  ...
};
```

or

Make x private instead of public and use following code:

```
class Base {
        int x;
        public:
            Base (int xx) {
                x = xx;
            }
            void display() {
                cout << "x = " << x << endl;
            }
    };

    class Derived : public Base {
        public:
            Derived (int xx) : Base (xx) {
            }
    };

    int main() {
        Derived d1(2);
        Derived *d = new Derived(10);
        d->display();
        d1.display();
        return 0;
    }
```