# C++11: How to access base class member in a derived class?

Tags: c++, c++11, syntax, constructor, derived-class

In a C++11 program I'd like to access the member `b2` of a base class
`Base` in a derived class `Derived` like so:

```cpp
struct Base
{
    const int b1 = 0;
    const int b2 = 0;
    Base (int b1) : b1(b1) {} // ok
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    Derived (int b1, int b2) : Base(b1), b2(b2) {} // error
    Derived (int b2) : Base(1), Base::b2(b2) {} // error
    Derived () : Base(1), this->b2(2) {} //error
};
```

Thread [accessing base class public member from derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13159659/1556746) claims that you can just access base class's members without any
further ado. Same here: [Accessing a base class member in derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153696/accessing-a-base-class-member-in-derived-class).

So could someone show me the correct syntax please?

g++ keeps throwing errors at me:

```
main.cpp: In constructor 'Derived::Derived(int, int)':
main.cpp:10:42: error: class 'Derived' does not have any field named 'b2'
main.cpp: In constructor 'Derived::Derived(int)':
main.cpp:11:41: error: expected class-name before '(' token
main.cpp:11:41: error: expected '{' before '(' token
main.cpp: At global scope:
main.cpp:11:5: warning: unused parameter 'b2' [-Wunused-parameter]
main.cpp: In constructor 'Derived::Derived()':
main.cpp:12:27: error: expected identifier before 'this'
main.cpp:12:27: error: expected '{' before 'this'
```

Comment: Only the constructor of the class itself can initialize a `const` variable. So you'll have to do it there.

Comment: Unrelated: you should prefer to initialize `b1` either inline (`= 0;`) or in the member initializer list (`: b1(...)`) but not both.

Comment: @alter Igel Does that cause any problems like undefined behavior?

Comment: Not undefined behaviour, the member initializer list simply overrides what appears in the default initializer (via [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization)). It's simply for clarity and maintainability reasons. Somebody else reading your code might be thrown off by the `= 0;` in `const int b1 = 0;` which actually has no effect, since this member is always initialized in the member initializer list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to access base class member in a derived class?

You can **access** the base class members either through `this` pointer or implicitly by using the name unless it is hidden.

> like so:
>
> ```
> Derived (int b1, int b2) : Base(b1), b2(b2) {} // error
> ```

While the derived class can *access* the members of the base, it cannot **initialise** them. It can only initialise the base as a whole, and if the base has a constructor, then that constructor is responsible for those members.

> So could someone show me the correct syntax please?

There is no syntax to do such initialisation. You must initialise the member in the base's constructor.